# How to select a row if a column meet a condition and if it does not, select another one? [Access 2010]

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I work with Access 2010.

I got a table in which there is no primary key, don't ask me why.
It looks like this.

```
      Code |  Dept  | Name | Status |
     ================================
       AA  |   01   | John |    A   |
       AB  |   00   | Bert |    A   |
       AB  |   01   | Yoan |    A   |
       BB  |   00   | Luke |    A   |
```

I want to select every Code ONCE. If an Code is under two dept, I want to select only the info from dept01.

So, I would want this result :

```
      Code |  Dept  | Name | Status |
     ================================
       AA  |   01   | John |    A   |
       AB  |   01   | Yoan |    A   |
       BB  |   00   | Luke |    A   |
```

I know I could use a Case in SQL server, but in Access, it doesn't want to collaborate.

Thanks for your help!

Phil

Comment: Left join the table to itself on code and dept in the outer table is equal to 01. Then keep only those where it is null or dept is equal to each other. On a side note, there is no case in Access, but there is IIf and Switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  This can be a bit tricky.  If a code only appears at most twice (as in your sample data), then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where dept = '01'
union all
select t.*
from t
where dept <> '01' and
      not exists (select 1 from t as t2 where t2.code = t.code);
```

This returns everything in "01" plus all rows from another department where the code is not in "01".

EDIT:

If you have multiple rows per code (and only one per department), then this also works:

```
select t.*
from t inner join
     (select code, max(iif(dept = '01', 1 0)) as has01, min(dept) as mindept
      from t
      group by code
     ) as tt
     on t.code = tt.code
where t.dept = '01' or (t2.has01 = 0 and t.dept = t2.mindept);
```

Comment: Thise seems like an excellent solution (I don't have more than two dept), but i do not understant the use of your "NOT EXISTS" clause.
Could you please explain its use?

Comment: Here is a blog post on the subject:  https://accessexperts.com/blog/2013/10/02/whether-to-exists-or-not-exists-that-is-the-question/.